# How to do you know when to add "the" before organisations' names?

Tags: definite-articles

On my grammar book, it says;

> many organisations have names with 'the'. ex. the European Union, the BBC

How do you know when you add the with organisations names?
Do most organisations names have the in front?

Comment: The organisation makes the choice itself. Though there's a famous London football club where the definite article is optional among at least older fans.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[using (or not) "The" before the name/title of the non-goverment organization](/questions/202404/using-or-not-the-before-the-name-title-of-the-non-goverment-organization)* Also see *[Definite article before schools, colleges, and universities](/questions/10020)* and many others.

Answer (score 0):

'The', being a definitive article, specifies one from a group.  So when the name of an organization contains a more general term, such as Union, States, or Association, along with additional descriptive words, 'the' is usually added.  I don't think there is a rule as such.